# Magento2 : Pop up on page load in magento home page

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options, custom, newsletter, popup

I thought there would be some support for the pop up in the Magento but did not succeed. I want to show the Email subscription popup on the page load on the home page.

The second thing is I am not using bootstrap so that `.modal` could not work in this case. Any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

Also, I want the default newsletter functionality in that popup. I tried to search the newsletter fields in the code but not succeeded.
Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is support for **pop ups / modals** in magento 2 without the need for bootstrap. See information from dev docs below:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

> **1. Magento 2 Pop Up**

Basically adding below code to your html and popup should show on page load:

```
<div id="custom-popup-modal">
  <p>Content Here...</p>
</div>

<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            modalClass: 'custom-popup-modal',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#custom-popup-modal'));

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#custom-popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        });     
    }
);
</script>
```

I like to have a timeout on these often so that it shows after a few seconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#custom-popup-modal').modal('openModal'); }, 3000);
```

> **2. Adding Newsletter**

Add below code to load magento newletter block within this modal:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe')->setTemplate('subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

So your modal should now look like below:

```
<div id="custom-popup-modal">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe')->setTemplate('subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

You will also need to update title in js and add additional content and some styling and this should be what you are after.

If you want to add to cms page from admin you will not be able to use the newsltter php so replace the modal content with something like below:

```
<form class="form subscribe" novalidate="novalidate" action="/newsletter/subscriber/new/" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div class="field newsletter">
            <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span>Sign Up for Our Newsletter:</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter" placeholder="Enter your email address" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="action subscribe primary" title="Subscribe" type="submit">
                <span>Subscribe</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

> **3. Styling Your New Popup**

I have added a new class to the popup modal so you can assign styles to just this modal. As you didn't want a title i have removed title from the JS which removes the heading and includes just the close button.

Within CSS add below to remove footer:

```
.custom-popup-modal .modal-footer {display:none;}
```

You can colour it and do whatever you with this using CSS:

```
.custom-popup-modal .modal-inner-wrap { background: #000; }
```

Another nice little trick is greying out the rest of the page when modal open:

```
.custom-popup-modal {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
```

Comment: hi ! if i want to add this on home where should i include it in the code files or from the admin side?

Comment: I would create a new template file and then add this to your cms_index_index.xml so that its added to homepage.

Comment: is it possible to add this from the admin side?? like content>pages>home page ?? actually i am quite new to magento and did not know how to add the template files

Comment: is it possible to add this from the admin side?? like content>pages>home page ?? actually i am quite new to magento and did not know how to add the template files

Comment: Most of it should be if you add to cms. Just not that php code form the newsletter. You could just get the hgtml markup for this tho.

Comment: @tech_geek Ive added the markup for the newsletter into the question add the bottom. Just replace this with the content of the modal

Comment: let me do this .

Comment: where i can put this timeout block?\

Comment: They can all go in same place its just hmtl and javascript so paste the whole thing in a CMS page is simplest thing to do really

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66170/discussion-between-harri-and-tech-geek).

Comment: @tech_geek Is this all working now? if so can you set as answer?

Comment: @herri i am getting a problem. There is header and footer but i want to show my content by removing header and footer is there any possibility because from the documentation i cannot see to hide these.

Comment: Well they have class modal-header and modal-footer so you can just create a rule in css e.g #custom-popup-modal .modal-footer{display:none;} however if you remove both then you will remove the close button. You can remove one and style the other so it blends in somehow however

Comment: actually i only want the close button in the header. Not in the footer. So the css is only way to do it ? i dont understand about blends.

Comment: Ok well to start #custom-popup-modal .modal-footer{display:none;} to css

Comment: Then add #custom-popup-modal .modal-title {display: none;}

Comment: Actually  that wont work properly let me get back to you

Comment: I have updated question which changes the JS slightly and added some CSS for the modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66170/discussion-between-harri-and-tech-geek)